How to make DosBox stop blinking when printing on the screen?
I'm new to assembler. I'm trying to do an "Space Invaders" game, but encountered a problem.
Every time I print the main spaceship and the enemies, I erase the whole screen, and then print again in the next position, for it not to be too fast, added a delay function, but it began blinking.
I read somewhere that you can solve that by changing the page you print while you are printing, and then change again, but I don't understand the concept well.
Print function (names are in Spanish because it's my mother tongue):
imprimeEnemigo proc 

push cx

mov al, 219
mov cx, 1               
call imprime
add dl, 1
mov al, 220 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
add dl, 1
mov al, 219 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
add dl, 1
mov al, 220 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
add dl, 1
mov al, 219 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
sub dh, 1
mov al, 220 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
sub dl, 1
mov al, 219 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
sub dl, 1
mov al, 220 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
sub dl, 1
mov al, 219 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
sub dl, 1
mov al, 220 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
add dh, 2
add dl, 1
mov al, 223 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
add dl, 2
mov al, 223 
mov cx, 1 
call imprime
pop cx
  ret
imprimeEnemigo endp    <----This is for printing enemies


imprime proc

mov bh, 0   ;BH = Page Number
mov ah, 02h ;Set cursor position, con los parametros de dh y dl
int 10h

mov ah, 09h ;Write character and attribute at cursor position
int 10h

ret
imprime endp    <---- Main print function with cursor positioning and printing (used also for the score and some other things)

This is how I clear my screen after each cycle:
mov ah, 0Fh
int 10h
mov ah, 0
int 10h

And this is how I print the main character:
imprime_Jugador proc

mov al, 219    
mov cx, 1      
call imprime
sub dl, 1
mov al, 220 
mov cx, 1
call imprime
add dl, 2
mov al, 220 
mov cx, 1
call imprime

    ret
imprime_Jugador endp

This is the delay function:
retardo proc
push ax
push bx
xor ax, ax
xor bx, bx

mov ax, cx ;cx begins at 1300, its a variable
ret2:
dec ax
jz finDec
mov bx, cx
ret1:
dec bx
jnz ret1
jmp ret2

finDec:
pop bx
pop ax
ret
retardo endp

This is how the game looks like: https://i.sstatic.net/QMpkgGnZ.png
I tried many things, but those didn't solve the problem at all, some reduced the blinking, but I want it to move smoothly through the screen


Every time I print the main spaceship and the enemies, I erase the whole screen, and then print again in the next position, for it not to be too fast, added a delay function, but it began blinking.

Erasing (before renewed printing) on the visualized screen is almost always a recipe for flicker. And erasing the whole screen is the worst!

I read somewhere that you can solve that by changing the page you print while you are printing, and then change again, but I don't understand the concept well.

For many of the legacy video modes, BIOS offers more than one display page. This enables us to look at one page (the 'active' page), and at the same time modify a page that is not being displayed. On that 'hidden' page we can erase all we want without it producing flicker.
Below is my approximation of what your program is doing and indeed it produces flicker:
  ORG  256

  mov  ax, 0003h    ; Screen 80x25 16 colors
  int  10h

  xor  si, si
Forward:
  mov  dx, si       ; Col
  mov  dh, 10       ; Row
  call imprimeEnemigo

  mov  dx, si       ; Col
  mov  dh, 16       ; Row
  call imprimeEnemigo

  mov  dx, si       ; Col
  mov  dh, 24       ; Row
  add  dl, 2
  call imprimeJugador

  mov  cx, 1300
  call retardo
  call clear

  inc  si           ; Col++
  cmp  si, 75
  jbe  Forward
  dec  si

Backward:
  mov  dx, si       ; Col
  mov  dh, 10       ; Row
  call imprimeEnemigo

  mov  dx, si       ; Col
  mov  dh, 16       ; Row
  call imprimeEnemigo

  mov  dx, si       ; Col
  mov  dh, 24       ; Row
  add  dl, 2
  call imprimeJugador

  mov  cx, 1300
  call retardo
  call clear

  dec  si           ; Col--
  jns  Backward
  inc  si
  jmp  Forward
; ------------------

imprimeEnemigo:
    mov  bl, 4
    push cx
    mov al, 219
    mov cx, 1               
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dh, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dh, 2
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 223 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 2
    mov al, 223 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    pop cx
    ret
imprime:
    mov bh, 0   ; BH = Page Number
    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h
    mov ah, 09h ; Write character and attribute at cursor position
    int 10h
    ret
clear:
  mov  ah, 0Fh
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 0
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  16h
  jz   .a
  mov  ah, 00h
  int  16h
  mov  ax, 0003h
  int  10h
  mov  ax, 4C00h
  int  21h
.a:
  ret

imprimeJugador:
    mov  bl, 1
    mov al, 219    
    mov cx, 1      
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1
    call imprime
    add dl, 2
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1
    call imprime
        ret

retardo:
  push ax
  push bx
  mov  ax, cx    ; cx begins at 1300, its a variable
.a:
  mov  bx, cx
.b:
  dec  bx
  jnz  .b
  dec  ax
  jnz  .a
  pop  bx
  pop  ax
  ret

Next comes an improved version that operates without flicker because everything gets prepared on a hidden page, and once that's done, just one BIOS function is enough to start displaying the new content:
mov  al, [HiddenPage]
mov  ah, 05h              ; BIOS.SetActiveDisplayPage
int  10h

With each toggle through BIOS, the program's definition of what is the visible page and the hidden page must change along:
xor  byte [HiddenPage], 1
xor  byte [VisiblePage], 1

This program only demonstrates the concept of using multiple display pages. There's a lot more to programming a Space Invaders game:
  ORG  256

  mov  ax, 0003h             ; Screen 80x25 16 colors
  int  10h                   ; -> VisiblePage is 0 and HiddenPage is 1

  xor  si, si
Forward:
  call RenderPicture
  call SetActiveDisplayPage
  mov  cx, 26
  call Wait
  call ExitOnKey
  inc  si                    ; Col++
  cmp  si, 75
  jb   Forward

Backward:
  call RenderPicture
  call SetActiveDisplayPage
  mov  cx, 26
  call Wait
  call ExitOnKey
  dec  si                    ; Col--
  jnz  Backward
  jmp  Forward
; ---------------------------
HiddenPage:  db 1
VisiblePage: db 0
; ---------------------------
Wait:
  xor  ax, ax
.a:
  dec  ax
  jnz  .a
  loop .a
  ret
; ---------------------------
ExitOnKey:
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  16h
  jz   .a
  mov  ah, 00h
  int  16h
  mov  ax, 0003h
  int  10h
  mov  ax, 4C00h
  int  21h
.a:
  ret
; ---------------------------
SetActiveDisplayPage:
  mov  al, [HiddenPage]
  mov  ah, 05h
  int  10h
  xor  byte [HiddenPage], 1
  xor  byte [VisiblePage], 1
  ret
; ---------------------------
ClearHiddenPage:             ; Can work unmodified on a graphical screen
  mov  bl, 0                 ; Black              like 640x350 16 colors
  mov  bh, [HiddenPage]
  mov  cx, 80                ; Characters per row
  xor  dx, dx                ; (0,0)
.a:
  mov  ah, 02h               ; BIOS.SetCursor
  int  10h
  mov  ax, 0920h             ; BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute (80x)
  int  10h
  inc  dh                    ; Row++
  cmp  dh, 25
  jb   .a
  ret
; ---------------------------
RenderPicture:
  call ClearHiddenPage

  mov  dx, si                ; Col
  mov  dh, 10                ; Row
  call imprimeEnemigo

  mov  dx, si                ; Col
  mov  dh, 14                ; Row
  call imprimeEnemigo

  mov  dx, si                ; Col
  mov  dh, 24                ; Row
  add  dl, 2                 ; Col
  call imprimeJugador
  ret
; ---------------------------
imprimeEnemigo:
    mov  bl, 4           ; Red
    push cx
    mov al, 219
    mov cx, 1               
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dh, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 219 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dh, 2
    add dl, 1
    mov al, 223 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    add dl, 2
    mov al, 223 
    mov cx, 1 
    call imprime
    pop cx
    ret
; ---------------------------
imprime:
    mov bh, [HiddenPage] ; BH = Page Number
    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h
    mov ah, 09h          ; Write character and attribute
    int 10h
    ret
; ---------------------------
imprimeJugador:
    mov  bl, 1           ; Blue
    mov al, 219    
    mov cx, 1      
    call imprime
    sub dl, 1
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1
    call imprime
    add dl, 2
    mov al, 220 
    mov cx, 1
    call imprime
    ret

Both programs were tested successfully in DOSBox 0.74 just now.
